# How do I do mysql "LIKE" in django?

Tags: mysql, django

SELECT * from myapp_mymodel WHERE code LIKE "914%";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend reading the manual, it clearly tells you how to do this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#startswith

```
MyModel.objects.filter(code__startswith='914')
```

Comment: That's fine if you're using a model, but what about with a `cursor`?